# Что быстрее Sql функции или php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

Как эффективно поступать,выполнять определённые процедуры на стороне *sql* либо же на стороне *php*? Например,эффективнее вытащить значения из базы, а затем применять к ним нужные операции посредством языка, или же эффективнее выполнить различные триггеры и функции на стороне *sql*, а потом просто вытащить результат?

**Что быстрее** ?

Comment: На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Какие-то задачи быстрее и удобнее решать на уровне БД, какие то на уровне php. Все зависит от того, какие именно манипуляции над данными вы производите. И зачастую сервер БД может вертеться на одном железе, а сервер приложений на другом.

Comment: sql всегда был быстрее, если задачу можно реализовать запросом.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov это очень сильное утверждение. С помощью `sql` можно например решать судоку, но чаще всего это менее удобнее и менее быстро, чем на другом ЯП. Или например задачи с большим количеством вычислений над данным, их бывает быстрее решить на php

Comment: А и кстати,по поводу железа,что БД на одном,а приложение веб на другом к примеру. Я правильно понимаю ,что приоритетнее будет ставить мощнее железо там где БД?

Comment: Мы сейчас рассуждаем о сферических конях в вакуме. Все зависит от той задачи, которую вы решаете. Где то большая часть нагрузки приходится на сервер БД, где то на сервер приложения. Повторюсь, на Ваш вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Ответ на такой вопрос можно получить только в разрезе конкретной задачи

Comment: @lDrakonl Стеб принимается, но если таблица вернет только нужно было всегда лучше, чем получить все и потом сортировать при помощи  php или других ресурсов. К примеру, что проще получить 10 нужных записей и работать с ними или сразу получить сумму или получить все 1000 и более потом сложить циклом?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov существуют запросы сложнее, чем `select * from table where id = 1`. Иногда бывает, что проще вытащить все данные и разобрать на сервере приложений, чем написать 400 строчный запрос заставить БД построить эффективный план этого запроса. Вопрос слишком общий, и на него нельзя отвечать, что sql всегда быстрее. Видел систему, в которой таблички справочники один раз вытаскиваются на сервер приложений, и потом СП для всех сессий использует ранее выгруженные массивы вместо дополнительных запросов в БД по справочникам. И это очень эффективно в конкретной задаче

Comment: @lDrakonl Дабы не флудить, отвечу еще раз "если задачу можно реализовать запросом"

Comment: Я и говорю о задачах, которые можно реализовать запросом

Comment: Вопрос типа: «[Кто сильнее: горилла или акула?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)». Все зависит от деталей. Если приведете конкретный пример, то можно будет хотя бы оценить.

Answer (score 5):

По собственному опыту - в большинстве случаев обработка на стороне БД быстрее по простой причине - для того, чтобы обработать данные на стороне приложения их надо сначало прочитать и обычно это одна из самых "дорогих" операций. Плюс при обработке данных на клиенте надо прибавить время получения/записи из/в БД.

Но иногда надо решать задачи, для которых пока не существует аппарата на стороне БД. Хороший пример задачи из разряда машинного обучения и искусственного интеллекта. Можно конечно попробовать реализовать весь функционал на SQL, но это никому ненужное "пере-изобретение колеса". В таких случаях БД используются просто как хранилища данных.

Т.е., в общем случае, если одну задачу можно эффективно решить и на стороне БД и на стороне приложения, то я бы выбрал решение на стороне БД, чтобы не гонять данные туда-сюда. Иначе ответ очевиден - на той стороне, которая больше для этого подходит.

PS бывают политические/стратегические решения когда по определенному ряду причин решают использовать БД только как хранилище - это тоже нормальная практика.

Выбор - куда ставить более мощное железо (для БД или для сервера приложений) будет очень сильно зависеть от того как используются данные сервера. Очень часто IO (быстрый storage system) и объем RAM для сервера БД важнее чем мощность процессоров. Конкретно - надо смотреть где узкое место...

Comment: Просто интересно,на примере АВИТО? Там где миллионы посетителей в сутки,сложные фильтры поиска в привязке с phinx и сложными запросами posgresql!Там как?

Comment: @GoodRA, честно говоря я ни знаю ни как АВИТО внутри устроено ни как снаружи (ни разу не открывал / не пользовался)...

Comment: Просто интересно,на примере АВИТО? - такие сервисы маштабируемы - нагрузка распределяется на несколько серверов.

Comment: @GoodRA, если интересно как устроена архитектура в АВИТО, то можно начать читать [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/company/avito/blog/330414/)